# Elemento clicable anular click

Tags: html, css

Dispongo de un toggle el cual quiero conservar su comportamiento, pero anulando la posibilidad del usuario de utilizarlo.

```css
body, html {
  background: #454545;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.btn {
  border: 1px solid #107a00;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  transition: background 600ms ease, color 600ms ease;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle {
  display: none;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle + label {
  cursor: pointer;
  min-width: 100px;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle + label:hover {
  background: none;
  color: #107a00;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle + label {
  background: none;
  color: #fff;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle + label:after {
  background: #107a00;
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transition: left 200ms cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle.toggle-left + label {
  border-right: 0;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle.toggle-left + label:after {
  left: 100%;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle.toggle-right + label {
  margin-left: 1px;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle.toggle-right + label:after {
  left: -100%;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle:checked + label {
  cursor: default;
  color: #f5dd01;
  transition: color 200ms;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle:checked + label:after {
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="toggle-on" class="toggle toggle-left" name="toggle" value="false" type="radio" checked>
  <label for="toggle-on" class="btn">Cable</label>
  <input id="toggle-off" class="toggle toggle-right" name="toggle" value="true" type="radio">
  <label for="toggle-off" class="btn">WiFi</label>
</div>
```

He probado a añadir al div el estilo `pointer-events: none;` pero continua permitiendo que el usuario lo use.

> **¿Cómo puedo caparlo?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder desactivar estos elementos, he usado `disabled`, cosa que es sencilla de implementar en JS. Lo que no se como lograr, es el cambio de CSS para que el resto de botones no cambie de colores (en mi ejemplo, solo lo quite). Esa parte te la dejo a ti jaja

```css
body, html {
  background: #454545;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.btn {
  border: 1px solid #107a00;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  transition: background 600ms ease, color 600ms ease;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle {
  display: none;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle + label {
  min-width: 100px;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle + label:hover {
  background: none;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle + label {
  background: none;
  color: #fff;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle + label:after {
  background: #107a00;
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transition: left 200ms cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle.toggle-left + label {
  border-right: 0;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle.toggle-left + label:after {
  left: 100%;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle.toggle-right + label {
  margin-left: 1px;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle.toggle-right + label:after {
  left: -100%;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle:checked + label {
  cursor: default;
  color: #f5dd01;
  transition: color 200ms;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle:checked + label:after {
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<input disabled id="toggle-on" class="toggle toggle-left" name="toggle" value="false" type="radio" checked>
<label disabled for="toggle-on" class="btn">Cable</label>
<input disabled id="toggle-off" class="toggle toggle-right" name="toggle" value="true" type="radio">
<label disabled for="toggle-off" class="btn">WiFi</label>
```